# Deque random access iterator comparison produces unexpected results

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, iterator, deque

I have this little snippet which behaves perfectly fine (as expected) on GCC.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::deque<int> values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int main()
{
    typedef std::deque<int>::iterator buf_iterator;

    buf_iterator itr = values.begin() + 1;

    const int K = 5;

    buf_iterator i = std::max(itr - K, values.begin());

    int pos = i - values.begin();

    std::cout << *i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, running on MSVC 2013 and 2015 produces a debug assertion: "deque iterator is not dereferencable". The value of `pos` in this case is `-4` while zero is expected.

1. Who is right, GCC or Visual Studio?
2. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`itr - K` is undefined behaviour because it decrements the pointer before the beginning, i.e. it is equivalent to:

```
auto it = values.begin();
--it;
```

And that is undefined.

GCC will catch this with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` defined:

```
/home/jwakely/gcc/5/include/c++/5.0.0/debug/safe_iterator.h:428:error: 
    attempt to retreat a dereferenceable iterator 5 steps, which falls 
    outside its valid range.

Objects involved in the operation:
iterator @ 0x0x7fff6fdb3450 {
type = N11__gnu_debug14_Safe_iteratorINSt9__cxx199815_Deque_iteratorIiRiPiEENSt7__debug5dequeIiSaIiEEEEE (mutable iterator);
  state = dereferenceable;
  references sequence with type `NSt7__debug5dequeIiSaIiEEE' @ 0x0x606360
}
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Ok. What would be the correct way to calculate the clamped ``i`` iterator?

Comment: Correctly, obviously ;-)  `itr - std::min(k, std::distance(values.begin(), itr))`

Comment: Basically, don't decrement more than the distance from `begin()` to `itr`. It's not complicated, you just need to be careful.

Comment: Thanks! Not my code btw, just experienced this while debugging.

Answer (score 5):

> Who is right, GCC or Visual Studio?

Both.

> Why?

Decrementing `begin()` is undefined behavior.